# jquery ajax dynamic form with dynamic inputs only submiting the first form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am in development phase of my freelancer market dashboard.The main idea of sending offer is like fiverr. seller will view buyer request which i am displaying through while loop

on view request it it is showing a model box of details of specific request 
on sending offer a new model box appears  containing seller gigs ..now here i created dynamic form with  respect to gigid ..

following is the JS  Code to view and submiting the form

```
 function showForm(seller)
{

    var a=seller;
    alert(a);
    $("."+a).toggle();




}

   function submitproposal(buyerId,gigsellerId) {
                         var buyerId=buyerId;
                        var gigsellerId=gigsellerId;



       var sellerRole = $("#sellerRole_"+gigsellerId).val();

       var sellerId = $("#sellerId_"+gigsellerId).val();
       var detail = $("#details_"+gigsellerId).val();

       var price = $("#price_"+gigsellerId).val();
       var duration = $("#duration_"+gigsellerId).val();
       var revision = $("#revision_"+gigsellerId).val();

       if ($("#checkbox1").is(":checked")) {
           var gigextra1 = $("#checkbox1").val();
       } else {
           var gigextra1 = '';
       }
       if ($("#checkbox2").is(":checked")) {
           var gigextra2 = $("#checkbox2").val();
       } else {
           var gigextra2 = '';
       }
       if ($("#checkbox3").is(":checked")) {
           var gigextra3 = $("#checkbox3").val();
       } else {
           var gigextra3 = '';
       }


       var gigId = $("#gigId_"+gigsellerId).val();

       var dataString = 'sellerRole=' + sellerRole + '&sellerId=' + sellerId + '&buyerId=' + buyerId + '&detail=' + detail + '&price=' + price + '&duration=' + duration + '&gigextra1=' + gigextra1 + '&gigId=' + gigId + '&gigextra2=' + gigextra2 + '&gigextra3=' + gigextra3 + '&revision=' + revision;
       alert(dataString);
        if (detail === "") {
           document.getElementById("error").innerHTML ="Please Give Details";

        }
        else if (price === "") {
           alert( 'Please Give Bugdet');
        }

        else {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "submitproposal.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {

                    var inserted = document.getElementById("Success").innerHTML = result;

                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    }
```

input fields with dynamic id's

```
 <?php

                                                            $selectgig=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * From freelance_gig WHERE  sellerId='$sellerId'");
                                                            $count=mysqli_num_rows($selectgig);

                                                            while($fetchgig=mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectgig)){
                                                                $gigSellerId=$fetchgig['id'];
                                                                $gigImage=$fetchgig['image'];
                                                                $title=$fetchgig['title'];


                                                                ?>

                                                                <ul style="border: ridge " >

                                                                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-gig_id="<?php echo $gigSellerId ?>" class="gigId" onclick="showForm(<?php echo $gigSellerId?>)" style="text-decoration: none;color: black">
                                                                        <img  width="100" height="100" src="<?php  echo $gigImage?>" style="margin-top: 5px;"><p><?php echo $title?></p></a>



                                                                    <div class="modal-body proposal <?php echo $gigSellerId?>" style="display: none;" >
                                                                        <div class="row">
                                                                            <div class="col-md-12">

                                                                                <h4>Please Fill The Following Fields </h4>


                                                                                <p id="error" style="color: red ;font-weight: bold"></p>
                                                                                <p id="Success" style="color: Green ;font-weight: bold"></p>
                                                                                <ul style="border: ridge " >

                                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                                        <input type="text" name="gigId"  id="gigId_<?php echo $gigSellerId?>" value="<?php echo $gigSellerId;?>" >
                                                                                        <input type="text" name="buyerId"  class="buyerIdnew" value="<?php echo $buyerId ?>">

                                                                                        <input type="text" name="sellerId"  id="sellerId_<?php echo $gigSellerId?>" value="<?php echo $sellerId?>" hidden >
                                                                                        <!--                                                                                        <input type="text" name="gigId"  id="gigId" value="--><?php //?><!--" hidden>-->
                                                                                        <br>
                                                                                        <label>
                                                                                            Describe Your Gig:
                                                                                        </label>

                                                                                        <input type="text"  class="pull-right" style="margin-right: 20px; width:200px;height: 50px;" name="gigdescription" id="details_<?php echo $gigSellerId?>">
                                                                                        <br>
                                                                                        <br>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                    <div  class="form-group" >
                                                                                        <label>
                                                                                            Price:
                                                                                            &nbsp;
                                                                                            &nbsp;

                                                                                        </label>

                                                                                        <span class="pull-right">$<input id="price_<?php echo $gigSellerId?>" type="number" style="width: 125px;margin-right: 20px;" min="5" max="5000" name="price" placeholder="maximum $5000"  ></span>
                                                                                        &nbsp;
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                    &nbsp;
                                                                                    &nbsp;
                                                                                    <div  class="form-group" >
                                                                                        <label>Duration </label>
                                                                                        <select id="duration_<?php echo $gigSellerId?>" name="duration" class="pull-right" style="margin-right: 20px;">
                                                                                            <option value="1" selected="">1 day</option>

                                                                                            <option value="2">2 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="3">3 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="4">4 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="5">5 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="6">6 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="7">7 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="8">8 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="9">9 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="10">10 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="11">11 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="12">12 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="13">13 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="14">14 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="15">15 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="16">16 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="17">17 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="18">18 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="19">19 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="20">20 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="21">21 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="22">22 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="23">23 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="24">24 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="25">25 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="26">26 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="27">27 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="28">28 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="29">29 days</option>

                                                                                            <option value="30">30 days</option>
                                                                                        </select>

                                                                                    </div>

                                                                                    <div class="form-group>">
                                                                                        <label>
                                                                                            Number Of Revisions(optional):


                                                                                        </label>
                                                                                        <select id="revision_<?php echo $gigSellerId?>" name="revisions" class="pull-right" style="margin-right: 20px;">
                                                                                            <option value="" selected="">Select</option>
                                                                                            <option value="1">1</option>
                                                                                            <option value="2">2</option>
                                                                                            <option value="3">3</option>
                                                                                            <option value="4">4</option>
                                                                                            <option value="5">5</option>
                                                                                            <option value="6">6</option>
                                                                                            <option value="7">7</option>
                                                                                            <option value="8">8</option>
                                                                                            <option value="9">9</option>
                                                                                            <option value="10">10</option>
                                                                                            <option value="11">11</option>
                                                                                            <option value="12">12</option>
                                                                                            <option value="13">13</option>
                                                                                            <option value="14">14</option>
                                                                                            <option value="15">15</option>
                                                                                            <option value="16">16</option>
                                                                                            <option value="17">17</option>
                                                                                            <option value="18">18</option>
                                                                                            <option value="19">19</option>
                                                                                            <option value="20">20</option>
                                                                                            <option value="-1">unlimited</option>
                                                                                        </select>

                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </ul>

                                                                                <br>
                                                                                <div class="form-group">

                                                                                    <a class="fa fa-play" onclick="ShowExtras(_<?php echo $gigSellerId?>)" style="text-decoration: none;color: black"> GiG Extra's (Optional) </a>
                                                                                    <div id="extras" style="display: none;">
                                                                                        <ul>
                                                                                            <li>
                                                                                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"  value="contentupload"> Content Upload
                                                                                            </li>
                                                                                            <li>

                                                                                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" value="responsivedesign">Responsive Design
                                                                                            </li>
                                                                                            <li>
                                                                                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" value="designcustomization">Design Customization
                                                                                            </li>
                                                                                        </ul>
                                                                                    </div>



                                                                                </div>
                                                                                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sellerRole; ?>" id="sellerRole_<?php echo $gigSellerId?>" >





                                                                                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn green submit" onclick="submitproposal(<?php echo $buyerId;?>,<?php echo $gigSellerId; ?>)" >
```

Comment: Sounds like a unique id attribute problem...though it looks like you have accounted for those...?

Comment: Can you show a couple of your example forms? Also, maybe there is a console error?

Comment: @Rasclatt there's not any console error ..the form against only first form form is submitted successfully

Comment: Can you post a couple of the html forms (just enough to reproduce the issue)?

Comment: @Rasclatt check I've edited the question .. these are the input fields with dynamic id's

Answer (score 0):

By which method are you binding the event?

Subsequent submission for model etc. doesn't occur because the event is bound before the element is rendered. If that's the case, To prevent that you can bind the event to body itself.

`$('body').on('click', '#button_id_dynamic', function(){
});`

Comment: how can i add arguments to this function like i was  doing before
 e.x

`function submitproposal(buyerId,gigsellerId)`

Comment: Its simple. Whatever you want to occur after the button is clicked, put everything inside the function (retrieving value from input, ajax, function calls etc)

Comment: Make the function call (along with the arguments), inside this function.

Comment: `$('body').on('click', '#submit', function(){

       function submitproposal(buyerId,gigsellerId) {
var buyerId=buyerId;
var gigsellerId=gigsellerId;
}
});`
is is okay ??

Comment: Yeah, should be okay. However, keep two things in mind-
1. As you said forms have dynamic ids. So I guess `#submit` should also be a dynamic id. But that will depend on your html structure. Or may be you can use a class for all such submit buttons. That will work for all subsequent submissions.
2. Keep in mind the scope of the variables buyerId etc and work accordingly.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: submitproposal is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Comment: my file contains php so unable to upload on js fiddle

Comment: From what I can gather, You don't need to use the onclick method with inline html. My suggestion would be no js in html.

HTML

`<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn green submit"  buyer-id="<?php echo $buyer-id?>" seller-id="<?php echo $seller-id ?>">`

JS

`<script>

function submitProporal(){
      //define function here
};

$('body').on('click', '.submit', function(){

//define variables
var $this= $(this);
var buyer_id= $this.attr('buyer-id');
var seller_id= $this.attr('seller-id');

//call function
submitProporal(buyer_id, seller_id);

});

</script>`